# Do I use memory barrier the wrong way?

Tags: c++

I simply implement Peterson Lock Algorithm, but it doesn't work rightly.
Here is the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
    volatile bool flag[2];
    volatile bool victim;
} peterson_lock_t;

void peterson_lock_init(peterson_lock_t &lock) {
    lock.flag[0] = lock.flag[1] = false;
    lock.victim = 0;
}

void peterson_lock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    lock.victim = id;
    lock.flag[id] = true;
    __asm__ __volatile__("" : : : "memory");
    while (lock.flag[1 - id] == false && lock.victim != id);
}

void peterson_unlock(peterson_lock_t &lock, int id) {
    lock.flag[id] = false;
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "peterson_lock.h"

peterson_lock_t lock;
int count = 0;

void *routine0(void *arg) {
    int *cnt = (int *)arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < *cnt; ++i) {
        peterson_lock(lock, 0);
        ++count;
        peterson_unlock(lock, 0);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *routine1(void *arg) {
    int *cnt = (int *)arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < *cnt; ++i) {
        peterson_lock(lock, 1);
        ++count;
        peterson_unlock(lock, 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    peterson_lock_init(lock);
    pthread_t thread0, thread1;
    int count0 = 10000;
    int count1 = 20000;
    pthread_create(&thread0, NULL, routine0, (void *)&count0);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, routine1, (void *)&count1);

    pthread_join(thread0, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

    printf("Expected: %d\n", (count0 + count1));
    printf("Reality : %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is not right:

> Expected: 30000
>   Reality : 24304
>
> Expected: 30000
>   Reality : 24316

OS:
*Linux ip-172-31-43-244 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 22:50:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: In what way is it working wrongly?

Comment: @Colin__s I test this and the result is wrong. I update the code of `main`.

Comment: `volatile` does not work as a memory barrier. Use `std::atomic` or other memory fence.  _"... This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution"_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @RichardCritten But here is the memory fence `__asm__ __volatile__("" : : : "memory");` between store and load.

Comment: Sorry, missed that, my fault, saw `volatile` and threads and jumped to my standard answer.  So why does `peterson_lock_t` have `volatile` members then?

Comment: @RichardCritten If I remove `volatile`, problem still exists.

Comment: @RichardCritten And cpu arch is intel x86-64

Comment: The `"memory"` specifier enforces a compile-time barrier (prevents the compiler reordering instructions).   You probably need a `"mfence"` specifier to prevent the CPU from reordering instructions.

Answer (score 0):

While condition also needs to be improved :

while (lock.flag[1 - id] == true && lock.victim == id)
continue;
Be in busy wait until the other thread has lock and you are the victim.

[Peterson Lock](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/)